# Is there a algorithm to remove some element that is the same as another?

Tags: java, list, algorithm

I want to remove **some outputs** that have the same value as another! 
Since Test1 = Test2 = Test5 = Test6 , so I want it to show only Test1 on the console!
Test3 =Test4 =Test7 = Test8, so I want it to show only Test3! 
........

The following code is what I did:

```
    boolean flg1 = true;
    List<List<String>> tmp1 = new ArrayList <>();
    List<List<String>> tmp2 = new ArrayList <>();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Size of the subset: " + subset.size());
    for(int i=0; i< subset.size();i++){
        tmp1=subset.get(i);

        // System.out.println("TMP1:"+ tmp1);

        for(int j=0; j<subset.size();j++){
        tmp2=subset.get(j);

        // System.out.println("TMP2:"+ tmp2.get(1));

            if(i != j && !compareOuterlist(tmp1,tmp2)){
                flg1=true;
                continue;
            }
        }
        if(flg1){
            count++;
            System.out.println("TEST " + (i+1) + ":"+ tmp1);
        }
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Total partition:"+ count);
}
public static boolean compareOuterlist(List<List<String>> p1, List<List<String>> p2){
    if(p1.size() != p2.size()){
        return false;
    }
    for(int i = 0;i < p1.size();i++){
        if(!(compareInnerlist1(p1.get(i),p2.get(i)))){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean compareInnerlist1(List<String> p1, List<String> p2){
    for(int i=0;i<p1.size();i++){
        if(!(p1.equals(p2))){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The following is my Output:

```
TEST 1:[[P11, X11, X22], [P11, X11, X22]]
TEST 2:[[P11, X11, X22], [P11, X11, X22]]
TEST 3:[[X11, X22], [P11, X22], [P11, X11]]
TEST 4:[[X11, X22], [P11, X22], [P11, X11]]
TEST 5:[[P11, X11, X22], [P11, X11, X22]]
TEST 6:[[P11, X11, X22], [P11, X11, X22]]
TEST 7:[[X11, X22], [P11, X22], [P11, X11]]
TEST 8:[[X11, X22], [P11, X22], [P11, X11]]
TEST 9:[[P11, X22], [X11, X22], [P11, X11]]
TEST 10:[[P11, X22], [X11, X22], [P11, X11]]
TEST 11:[[P11, X22], [X11, X22], [P11, X11]]
TEST 12:[[P11, X22], [X11, X22], [P11, X11]]
```

Comment: are you looking for Set? Search HashSet, TreeSet in java

Comment: You can see my suggested algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Java 8 Streams, you can do it using `distinct()`:

```java
List<List<List<String>>> result = subset.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want to do it in a loop while printing, it can be done using a `Set`:

```java
Set<List<List<String>>> distinct = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < subset.size(); i++) {
    List<List<String>> tmp1 = subset.get(i);
    if (distinct.add(tmp1))
        System.out.println("TEST " + (i+1) + ":"+ tmp1);
}
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Total partition: " + distinct.size());
```

*Output*

```
TEST 1:[[P11, X11, X22], [P11, X11, X22]]
TEST 3:[[X11, X22], [P11, X22], [P11, X11]]
TEST 9:[[P11, X22], [X11, X22], [P11, X11]]

Total partition: 3
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer helps me a lot!!

Comment: Sorry! I just found that TEST 3 and TEST 9 have the same element , but the elements are positioning in the different order!. So, Is there any way to remove TEST 9?

Comment: @Insider They are lists. Lists are *ordered*, so [A,B] is different from [B,A]. If you want to change the requirements, then that's a new question, so create a new question and make sure to list all the rules. This question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ArrayList of String an whenever you wanna print the test , you add the result to that List , but before printing and incrementing count , you'll have to make sure that what you'll print doesnt exist on the list :

```
if(flg1){
        if !(Your_List.conatains("TEST " + (i+1) + ":"+ tmp1)) {
             System.out.println("TEST " + (i+1) + ":"+ tmp1);
             count++;
        }
        Your_List.add("TEST " + (i+1) + ":"+ tmp1);
    }
```